# ADD multiple objects with form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to do something which I would think is quite common, but I'm just really unsure how to realise it.

I have modal **'Requirement'**. Every requirement has there own **name** and **unique code**. I want to show form with `REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES list` with checkboxs. User can select checkboxes which requirements they need. How to make it in Django?

[image]

**models.py:**

```
class Requirement(models.Model):
     code = models.UUIDField(_('Code'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     symbol = models.CharField(_('Symbol'), max_length=250)
     name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class RequirementAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES,)

    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ('symbol',)

 REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES = (
     ('A', 'Name A'),
     ('B', 'Name B'),
     ('C', 'Name C'),
 )
```

**views.py:**

```
def requirement_add(request, project_code):
data = dict()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RequirementAddForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        symbols = form.cleaned_data.get('symbol') # List of symbols which user selected ['A', 'C']
        for symbol in symbols:
            requirement = form.save(commit=False)
            requirement.symbol = symbol
            requirement.name = symbol.get_symbol_display() #???
            requirement.save()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        requirements = Requirement.objects.filter()
        context = {'requirement': requirement, 'requirements': requirements}
        data['html_requirement'] = render_to_string('project/requirement_list.html', context)
    else:
        data['form_is_valid'] = False
else:
    form = GroupRequirementAddForm()
context = {'form': form}
data['html_requirement_form'] = render_to_string('project/requirement_add.html', context, request=request)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: you can use django forms

Comment: @SurbhitWagle can you check my post again pls. I add more details. I use  `MultipleChoiceField` in my form. In view I use `symbols = form.cleaned_data.get('symbols')` which give me list of symbols which was selected by user. For example ['A', 'C']. I need to save second option of tuple (human readable value) to name field. How to make it? I tried this but not sure that its correct: `requirement.name = symbol.get_symbol_display()`

Comment: you can use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: @SurbhitWagle I read information from this link before. I use choise in form,  not in model. So I dont know is this line in views would be correct `requirement.name = symbol.get_symbol_display()` I want to store second value of tuple to name field.

Comment: did you try using `requirement.name = symbol.get_name_display()`

Comment: I did little mistake. In form must be fields = ('symbol',). So I tried next code `requirement.name = symbol.get_symbol_display()` but it raise error:` AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_name_display'`

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to save second option of tuple (human readable value) to name field?!